# How do I print elements of structures contained in an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have created an array of structure as a global variable. I initialised the array in a function and I could print out the elements of the structure from there. My problem is that I can't print out values of the array in another function( main() in my case) other than the one I used to initialise the array. Please how can I print those values? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
typedef struct s{
    char *value;
} S;

S list[2];

void function( ){
    char val1[] = "val1";
    char val2[] = "val2";
    S v1 = {val1};
    S v2 = {val2};
    list[0] = v1;
    list[1] = v2;
    printf("%s\n", list[1].value); //prints val2
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    function();
    printf("%s", list[1].value); //prints nonsense 
    return 0;
}
```

What I have tried :

1. I modified function() to take list as an argument( function (list)) and declared list in main() instead. It didn't work.
2. I modified function to return list (S* function()), it didn't work.
3. I used an array of integers ( instead of structure i.e. int list[2], declared it as a global variable and initialised it in function()) and everything worked fine, suggesting that the problem is from how I am accessing structure, but I just can't figure it out.
4. I searched the internet, but couldn't get a similar problem.

Comment: Your structure contains a pointer which you assign with the address of a local variable. After `function` the address is no longer valid.

Comment: Thank you very much. After effecting the corrections, it worked like magic!

Comment: If it solved your problem feel free to [accept it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :).

Comment: @youngwarlock: Note that, if you are not planning on modifying `.value` afterwards, `list[0].value = "something";` will work fine.

Comment: @Groo: thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `function` you assign an address of a local variable to your structure. After returning from `function` this address is no longer valid. You could either make it `static` or allocated it dynamically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s
{
    char *value;
} S;

S list[2];

void function( )
{
    char val1[] = "val1";
    char val2[] = "val2";
    //Note that you are creating a copy of "val1" here which can be avoided by changing it to char *val1 = "val1";

    list[0].value = malloc(strlen(val1)+1); //allocate space for val1 + NUL-terminator
    strcpy(list[0].value, val1); //copy string
    list[1].value = malloc(strlen(val2)+1);
    strcpy(list[1].value, val2);

    //You could also use the function strdup which allocates memory and duplicates the string
    //list[0].value = strdup(val1);

    printf("%s\n", list[1].value); //prints val2
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    function();
    printf("%s", list[1].value);

    free(list[0].value); //Don't forget to free.
    free(list[1].value);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char val1[] = "val1"` is unnecessary, just use `strcpy(list[0], "val1");`. If the string is a literal, then simply `list[0].value = "val1";` would also work. Also, `void function( )` should probably be `void function(void)`.

Comment: @Groo Yes, `val1` in `strlen` and `strcpy` could be directly replaced with `"val1"`, but I wanted to show how he could correctly write any string into the structure.

Comment: my point was that this makes an unnecessary copy of the string literal. If you compare these [three examples](https://godbolt.org/z/iChr-6), there is an initial copy to the stack in the first example, the second example only contains a malloc+copy, and the third one just gets a pointer to the string literal.

Comment: @Groo Yes, another approach to avoid the unnecessary copy would be to change `char val1[] = "val1";` to `char *val1 = "val1";` (which is basically the second example with an additional pointer). The third example is slightly different since string literals do not have to be freed and you can't modify them. I will write a small comment in my answer to clarify it.